# BATCH : make a loop with command

Tags: batch-file

I have a problem, it's when i want to echo each f in "dir /aa ..." i have a bug.
I want all files with A atributes :

```
for /f %%f in ('dir /aa c:\Users\Alexis\Desktop') do (
    echo %%f
)

pause > nul
```

[the bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouLbh.png)

Thank you

Comment: what about `dir` switches `/b` and `/a-d`? Also `for` parameter `tokens=*"` or `"delims="` can be helpful.

Comment: There is extensive information on the [`DIR`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) command at [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/); you might want to bookmark this site.

Comment: Thank you : i use dir /b /aa-d-s and it's work

Comment: @A.Lebrun add `"delims="` to the `for` loop to also handle filenames with spaces.